# RailsのRspecでRansack部分をテストしたいが、undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClassとエラーが出てしまいます

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Rspecに関する質問です。
Ransackの動作がしっかり行われているかどうかを、Rspecテストのコードを書いているのですが、検索実行のシミュレーションの部分で

```
NoMethodError:
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

と出ます。

```
ファイルは以下の通りです。
```

spec/controllers/master_costs_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe MasterCostsController do
  describe 'GET #index' do


    context 'when master_costs searched' do
      before do
        create_list(:master_cost, 10) #検索用のデータ
      end

      specify do
        @params[:q][:name_cont] = 'あああ'  ###この行の[:name_cont]がおかしいと言われているのですが、どうしたら良いのかわかりません...検索パラメーターを受け取るために記述しているのですが.....
        get :index, @params
        expect(assigns(:master_costs)).to match_array([@data1])
      end
    end 
  end    
end
```

spec/factories/master_costs.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :master_cost do

    sequence(:code)
    sequence(:name) { |i| "MasterCostName#{ i }" }
    cost_class      { MasterCost.cost_classes.values.sample }
    budger_class    { MasterCost.budget_classes.values.sample }

    @params = Hash.new,
    @params[:q] = Hash.new
  end
end


FactoryGirl.define do
  before :each, class: MasterCost do
    @data1 = create(:data, code: 1, name: 'あああ', cost_class: 1, budger_class: 'A')
    @data2 = create(:data, code: 2, name: 'いいい', cost_class: 2, budger_class: 'AB')
    @data3 = create(:data, code: 3, name: 'ううう', cost_class: 3, budger_class: 'A')
    @params = Hash.new
    @params[:q] = Hash.new
  end
end
```

エラーログ

```
Failures:

  1) MasterCostsController GET #index when master_costs searched
 Failure/Error: @params[:q][:name_cont] = 'あああ'

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/controllers/master_costs_controller_spec.rb:28:in `block (4         levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.37994 seconds (files took 9.51 seconds to load)
3 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/master_costs_controller_spec.rb:27 #  MasterCostsController GET #index when master_costs searched

Randomized with seed 65361
```

お手数おかけしますが、わかる方いましたら少しのヒントでも嬉しいのでお力添え願います。
     @params[:q][:name_cont] = 'あああ'の[:name_cont]がパラメータを受け取るにはどのように改善する必要があるのでしょうか？？

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/39271 マルチポスト

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しましたので、一応報告させていただきます。

```
Failure/Error: @params[:q][:name_cont] = 'あああ'
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

=>ハッシュオブジェクトがありませんとのことでした。

全ての原因はfactories/master_costs.rbの

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  before :each, class: MasterCost do
    @data1 = create(:data, code: 1, name: 'あああ', cost_class: 1, budger_class: 'A')
    @data2 = create(:data, code: 2, name: 'いいい', cost_class: 2, budger_class: 'AB')
    @data3 = create(:data, code: 3, name: 'ううう', cost_class: 3, budger_class: 'A')
    @params = Hash.new
    @params[:q] = Hash.new
  end
end
```

の

```
@params = Hash.new
@params[:q] = Hash.new
```

の箇所を
master_costs_controller_spec.rbに移動し

```
context 'when master_costs searched' do
  before do
    create_list(:master_cost, 10) #検索用のデータ
  end
  before do
    @data1 = create(:master_cost, code: 112, name: 'あああ', cost_class: 1, budger_class: 'A')
  end
  specify do
    @params = Hash.new
    @params[:q] = Hash.new
    @params[:q][:name_cont] = 'あああ'
    get :index, @params
    expect(assigns(:master_costs)).to match_array([@data1])
  end
end
```

とすればすべてが解決されました。エラー文の'[]'をハッシュのことではなく配列だと勘違いしていたため時間がかかってしまいました。